# i got Windows BlueScreen With Stop Code: Memory Management. when running Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Here's my Code

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

is my computer the problem that it's causing the problem?
ram 8gb
core i5-4460
gtx 760

i've had this computer more than 10 years btw

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.